# Add +1 if partial query exists in a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to check if a partial string exists in a dictionary key and if exists, add the value +1.

```
dic = {
    'partial sentence':2,
    'complete sentence':1
}

print(any('partial' in sentence for sentence in dic))
```

At this time I can say "partial" exists in "partial sentence", but, how do I add +1 to the value?

Answer (score 1):

dictionary comprehension. In python3

```py
In [6]: newdict = { k : v + 1 if 'partial' in k else v for k, v in dic.items() }

In [7]: newdict
Out[7]: {'partial sentence': 3, 'complete sentence': 1}

In [8]:
```

Comment: Creating a new `dict` may not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it explicitly while iterating over the dict.

```
for sentence in dic:
    if 'partial' in sentence:
        dic[sentence] += 1
```

Comment: dic[sentence] +=1

Comment: Oh, right; there were *three* instances of `key` I meant to replace with `sentence` :)